# Removing a specific element from a json array in golang

Tags: json, go

I tried a few options but with no results. If anyone knows some kind of solution it would be nice. I was trying with [buger/jsonparser](http://github.com/buger/jsonparser) because of the parsing speed. Lets say i want to exclude object3 and assign it to MYVARIABLE

for exaple :

```
data:=[{object1}, {object2}, {object3}]

//this function iterates through the array
jsonparser.ArrayEach(data, func(key []byte, dataType jsonparser.ValueType, offset int, err error) {

    MYVARIABLE:=key

    return
})
```

Comment: Add some code as examples please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that you have successfully parsed your data to struct.
And you would have an array of yourStruct `[]yourStruct`, and assign the third element with empty struct like this :

```
yourStruct[2] = YourStruct{}
```

the third element is still there with empty value. And unfortunately in go you can't assign struct with `nil` value.

or you can convert the `[]byte` of your data that has your json to `string` and iterate it over to the their element and remove it with empty char, but this would be an expensive approach.

As [Kaedys](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4551301/kaedys) said you can remove your array struct using slice like this :

```
yourStruct = yourStruct[:2]
fmt.Printf("resutl struct = %+v\n", yourStruct)
```

Comment: You can easily omit an entry from a slice though.  `yourStruct = append(yourStruct[:2], yourStruct[3:]...)`.  As long as the slice has a length of 3 or more, that won't panic (even though index 3 in a slice of length 3 is an invalid index, the runtime is coded to handle it properly).